# How to solve ClassCastException when using BitSet as key in Java Map

Tags: java, equals, classcastexception, bitset

I am using:

```
Map <BitSet,Double> Mymap=new TreeMap<>();
```

When I try to call:

```
Mymap.contains(someBitSetObject)
```

I am getting following run time error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.BitSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:343)
    at java.util.TreeMap.containsKey(TreeMap.java:227)
```

......................

Although the BitSet class has its own equals method, `TreeMap` is not calling it. I'm stuck. How do I check if the `MyMap` already contains a key and I need a Key of type `BitSet`?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) relies on the keys being sortable - not just equatable:

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a `Comparator` provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

`BitSet` doesn't implement `Comparable`. *Either* you need to provide a `Comparator<BitSet>` to the `TreeMap` constructor, or use a different kind of map. If you don't care about the sort order, use `HashMap` or `LinkedHashMap`. If you *do* care about the sort order, you'll need to give that ordering yourself.

Comment: I am not using any any sort feature. Problem is with map.containsKey

Comment: You are using `TreeMap`. I advise you to study the Javadoc of classes you are using.

Comment: @ItsKaur: From the documentation of `TreeMap`: "The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys" - so yes, you *are* using a sort feature.

Comment: @ JonSkeet and Marko: Thank you very much :-)) I changed TreeMap to HashMap and it seems working!